# Is this a legitimate math-move?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have assumed $P=f(x)$, where $f'(x)<0$, $f''(x)>0$.

I want to find $\frac{\partial x}{\partial P}$.

Since I have $P = f(x)$, I can find $\frac{\partial P}{\partial x} = f'(x)$.

From that can I write down $dP= f'(x)dx$? and then solve for $\frac{\partial x}{\partial P} = \frac{1}{f'(x)}$.

Comment: Well, yes: it's the known theorem about the derivative of the inverse function. Of course, one must *then* retrieve the appropiate variable.